# Ubuntu 20.4 LTS switching to read only

Tags: 20.04, read-only

I have been using Ubuntu for more than a decade. Recently I am using Ubuntu 20.4 lts. It has switched to a read only mode on its own. No idea how this happened. What should I do to make it read and write mode and also prevent this from happening. My docs saved on the pendrive have also become read only. Thanks for your help.
AG

Comment: Hello. The most common cause of switching to read only is a failing drive. Happening to the thumb drive as well as internal drive at the same time is super unusual. Have you tried to run a fsck on the hard dixk?

Comment: You should be reading your logs which will provide a clue as to why the system (I assume you mean *file-system*) flipped from RW to RO. Usually it's the result of hardware issues (eg. power issues, or failing components) unless an owner/operator with `sudo` rights made a unwise change in the session prior to the issue first occurring (usually the session before it occurred) but you've provided few stats. I'd check PSU, disk drive health, RAM etc...   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. My laptop is partitioned into windows and Ubuntu. Only the Ubuntu section is showing this problem. The hard drive had crashed last July. I am using a new one. One thing that happened the second time is that while the pen drive was attached it suddenly got disconnected. This problem appeared after it got connected again. This happened on its own. No one except me has permission to enter my laptop. Do i need to reload Ubuntu again. If so, what guarantee that this will not repeat itself?

Comment: As I already stated, you should read your logs for exact clues as to the problem, we cannot read them unless they're provided. You mention a disconnected thumb-drive; if it was being used at the time - then that could have corrupted data, especially if you continued using the machine after it was re-connected without re-starting the OS cleanly; ie. your last comment describes a user-caused corruption event unless it was handled properly; and you're vague on details; did you cleanly dismount or use SysRq commands? before re-connecting the drive? cleanly mount after reconnecting etc.. or restart

Comment: I am not a developer. I just use Ubuntu as my os. Where and how do i read the logs? After it disconnected, it reconnected on its own. I did cleanly dismount after that but the system had become read only by then.

Comment: You can read system messages via `dmesg` or systemd logs using `journalctl`.  If you know the time the issue occurred; systemd's logs use human time so can be easiest to scan (the kernel log I mentioned is time since boot). If you were only using the *disconnected/reconnected* thumb-drive for data the effect maybe minor, if it had system on it I'd have rebooted to avoid further corruption.  A file-system flips RO when errors are detected to prevent data loss; using it for RW can do more damage thus it's prevented.  It's ~best to `fsck` or perform file-system checks first on *fs* that is RO

Comment: I have found the log. But unable to cut and paste it here. If you have an email id i can send it. It shows crash on March 18  14.08  - crash (1:15)

Comment: It also shows march 18 15.31-18.07(02:36) March 18 15.31 - down(02:35)

Comment: The problem I encountered with the 2 nd pendrive was on March 25.The first one was much before March 18.